# Highlight Overlapping Dates based on Range with Unique Identifier (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, date, overlapping

First time asking a question and very new to VBA code. I'm trying to write VBA code to highlight when dates overlap across a range of cells based on a unique identifier. Here is an example of the code:

[image]

Basically i'm looking to compare the dates associated with the first unique identifier (1234 - which is three rows), highlight whether any dates are overlapping and then move to the next unique identifier (5678) and do the same.

Hope this is clear. Any help is appreciated.

Ciarán

Comment: please see advice on how to make a minimally reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO!

You did forget to include the VBA you already wrote yourself, as that would help people here helping you (and this is not a free coding service platform ;)). Secondly, you could do that without VBA, just using the COUNTIFS formula and conditional formatting. For that solution, see e.g. this tutorial on COUNTIFS: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function and this one on conditional formatting: https://exceljet.net/conditional-formatting-with-formulas